# Each time I save a file, Spacemacs will try and parse my bibliography bibtex file. How can I stop that?

Tags: org-mode, auto-save, bibtex, helm-bibtex

I use Spacemacs and it is great. But for some reason, each time I save a file--usually an `org` file, Spacemacs will try and parse my default `bibtex` file. And that file is relatively large, so it adds a weird amount of time either when saving or even when auto-saving. I am not sure where to look to fix this.

I use `helm-bibtex` which is again, wonderful. But each time I save a file, in the *Messages* I see:

```
Saving file /home/.../myfile.org...
Wrote /home/.../myfile.org
Parsing bibliography file ~/Dropbox/.../library.bib ...
forward-sexp: Scan error: "Unbalanced parentheses", 2702612, 6340258
```

And on each save it seems to find some parsing errors--so the save is triggering a validation or parsing of this large `bibtex` file.

I was looking in the `after-save-hook` and `before-save-hook` variables, but I did not see anything that immediately caught my attention. Is there something that could be causing this, either in the `helm-bibtex` settings or somewhere?

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try with `emacs -q` to make sure that it does not happen  without yuour init file. If indeed it does not happen, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @NickD good idea. I will give that a shot and see if I can find the source. Thanks for the suggestion. I have not fiddled with my config in a while, haha.